# SpagoBI Filter gives Javascript validation error

Tags: javascript, spagobi

I have developed some reports on SpagoBI 5.1

When I run it on my local machine it doesnot gives any error and works fine.

When I have deployed them on cloud server with redhat 6.5
it runs all the charts without filters nicely but when some charts has filters then it throws an following error.
Please check attached image for the error.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was the validators check box was selected on analytical driver config.

Which we need to remove so that it wont check for validation on a analytical driver.

Please find attached image.

[image]